# knex.raw.query() gives error with ORDER BY binding

Tags: knex.js

I am adding **order by** binding to a knex raw query in the following way.

```
-- Here userIds = [1,2,3] and dataOrder='DESC'

knex.raw.query("
 select from users
 where userId in ?
 order by created ?
",
[
 userIds,
 dataOrder
])
```

I get this error saying

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near ''DESC'' at line 1
```

I tried **dataOrder** with both single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

When providing SQL keywords as binding values with `.raw()`, you need to wrap the value with another call to `knex.raw()`. We also need to deal with some more complexity because there is no agreement on array bindings between database providers. That leaves us with something like this:

```
const dataOrder = "DESC";
const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
const userIdBindings = userIds.map(_ => "?").join(",");

knex.raw(`
  SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE id IN (${userIdBindings})
    ORDER BY ??
    ?
  `,
  [...userIds, "created", knex.raw(dataOrder)]
)
```

Note the double `??` because this denotes an [identifier binding](https://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings).

You might like to consider avoiding `.raw()` where possible, since as you have discovered it can be error-prone. Consider:

```
knex('users')
  .whereIn('id', userIds)
  .orderBy('created', dataOrder)
```

Much simpler! If your actual query is more complex, feel free to post it: most things are possible with the query builder syntax.

Comment: good answer but im confused what the lone ? on the line after ORDER BY is for

Comment: It's a placeholder in the raw query. It'll be populated by whatever `knex.raw(dataOrder)` evaluates to (in this case, `DESC`).